# Ubuntu 20.04 sleep mode error

Tags: suspend

It is the first time I have posted in the community.

I have a problem with Ubuntu 20.04, every time my Dell Inspiron 3493 laptop goes into sleep mode I get the following error. How can I solve that?

[image]

Comment: The error indicates that your disk is in a read-only mode.  This can happen for a few reasons, and my first suggestion would be to create a bootable USB, boot from the USB and run fsck on your drives  `sudo fsck -f /dev/xxxx` replacing "xxxx" with the appropriate descriptor for your partitions

Comment: I already did, and it keeps showing the same error